# Query on partition size

Tags: partitioning

Have provided **25GB(/)**, **8GB(Swap)** and left the balance **space(around 280GB)** as it is with out formatting during the installation. What i did is correct or will this be effected in future for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

25 Gb is enough for the base files but if you put /home in there and use /home also as some sort of file server (so to keep video files) it will run out fairly quickly. Easily solved by regurarly removing large files as to keep only what is needed.

Ubuntu/Linux is very flexible when it comes to space. If at anytime 25Gb is not enough it is fairly simple to add space with gParted.

So your method can be correct for now and the future.

Comment: Thank You. So i can use gParted to add more space to "/" when ever it is required right?

Comment: Yes, it is called 'resizing'. Painfully slow if the disc is near full though ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you are not formatting your 280 GB partition no problem but want to storing more data/stuff in ubuntu(home) drive then try to increase 25 GB to more, after installing linux/ubuntu 12.04 of higher then approx 12 GB drive space is used.

- In future you can create virtual partitions of 280 GB for another use.
- If you want to install windows then create NTFS partitions.

Use [Gparted Partition Editior](http://gparted.org/) to create partitions.

Comment: Thank you. What exactly is virtual partition? Am not going to use windows in my laptop so should i add all space to "/" or should i keep the free space as it is?

Comment: virtual partition mostly use to create dual boot system like windows, unix and other OS with ubuntu but now you are created right partition and can use 280 GB as your choice. You can create further partitions of 280 GB or use whole as it is. You should create ext4 type partitions instead of "/".

Answer (score 0):

If you have laptop in which you are not going to use in dual boot with windows and having complete HDD around 300 GB then the partition which will be modest to performance as well as considering any chances to install windows again may be

1st partition  500 MB ext4 JFS mounted as /root  (this will hold your kernel and grub)
2nd partition  4 GB   Swap (If you have RAM 2 GB otherwise use 2*times of RAM size)
3rd partition  56 GB  ext4 JFS mounted as /    (This will hold all types of settings as well as /Home)
4th  parttion  remaing all space as NTFS file system for having data backup in case your Linux system get completely down.